# WordPress LIKE statement for fetching multiple values is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to fetch all the related data from a custom MySQL table using like the statement, but the query is not working.

```
$final_search = "$name $email $subject $hobby";
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "credofy_contact_form";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT your_name, your_email, your_phone, your_hobby FROM $table_name WHERE your_name, your_email, your_phone, your_hobby LIKE '$final_search'");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple `column`, you should use the `LIKE` query in the way

```
SELECT your_name, your_email, your_phone, your_hobby 
FROM table_name 
WHERE your_name LIKE '%keyword%' 
OR your_email LIKE '%keyword%' 
OR your_phone LIKE '%keyword%'
OR your_hobby LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, your solution is working but it`s showing all the rows after showing matching data.

Comment: @gauravmishra you can fetch which column values you want to fetch like select youremail......